# Splitting a graph

Tags: python, machine-learning, math, image-processing, graph

I have an array of 575 points.

When I represent it on graph, I get following curve shown in the attached image.

I want to split it in sub graphs when slope becomes 0 or you can say when the graph becomes parallel to x-axis.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Graph containing array of 575 points]

Comment: What did you try so far? How are you hoping the result will look? Are you providing the data points or a link to them?

Comment: Interesting, however it's better suited to stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to have some degree of smoothness, otherwise you will have as a result many small separated regions of the graph.

You also may need to specifically define what you want to consider as parallel to the x-axis.

I suggest to start by moving a running window of certain length that categorizes each range being studied as horizontal given certain condition.

This condition can be something like "all values are inside certain range". This condition may take into account characteristics like the variance and the mean of the points inside the window. For example, "all values are between 101% and 99% of the mean."